# Is there a jvm argument that causes the jvm to create an hprof file when the jvm starts up

Tags: java, jvm

One of our testers keeps getting a small hprof file created on his windows environment when he starts our application.

- The hprof file is only showing up on his windows instance. Other testers aren't seeing this
- The hprof file appears every time he starts it.
- The hprof file is very small (45mb). There are no OutOfMemoryErrors or anything useful in the hprof file for that matter.
- The jvm doesn't exit
- The application works just fine on his installation after startup.

Is there some jvm argument that can be specified at startup (in this case, through some environment variable) which creates an hprof file at **startup**? I know if you specify cpu=samples it will create one on exit.

I'm reasonably convinced that it is a system setting. But I have no idea which one. We are running Oracle's jre 1.6_024 and the jvm is running as part of a startup of tomcat 7.

MORE INFORMATION HERE IS MY SET OUTPUT.

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Administrator>SET
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Windows\java\lib\jtapi.jar;.;;
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=RAJSERVER
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Administrator
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\RAJSERVER
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=4
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\company\app\resources;C:\Program Files (x
86)\company\app\resources;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows
\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell    \v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;%APPDATA%\Python    \Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.pyw
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=170a
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1
TMP=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\1
USERDOMAIN=RAJSERVER
USERNAME=Administrator
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Administrator
windir=C:\Windows
```

Here is a dump of my system properties once the application is started by tomcat.

```
prps awt.toolkit = sun.awt.windows.WToolkit
prps catalina.home = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Tomcat
prps catalina.useNaming = true
prps com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.protocol = plain ssl
prps com.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout = 10000
prps file.encoding.pkg = sun.io
prps file.encoding = UTF-8
prps java.awt.graphicsenv = sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
prps java.awt.printerjob = sun.awt.windows.WPrinterJob
prps java.class.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Tomcat\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Tomcat\bin\tomcat-juli.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\lib\tools.jar;C:\Windows\java\lib\jtapi.jar;C:\Windows\java\lib\jtracing.jar
prps java.class.version = 50.0
prps java.endorsed.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Tomcat\endorsed
prps java.ext.dirs = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
prps java.home = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre
prps java.io.tmpdir = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Tomcat\temp
prps java.library.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\webapp\resources
prps java.naming.factory.initial = org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
prps java.naming.factory.url.pkgs = org.apache.naming
prps java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
prps java.runtime.version = 1.6.0_27-b07
prps java.specification.name = Java Platform API Specification
prps java.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
prps java.specification.version = 1.6
prps java.vendor.url = http://java.sun.com/
prps java.version = 1.6.0_27
prps java.vm.info = mixed mode
prps java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM
prps java.vm.specification.name = Java Virtual Machine Specification
prps java.vm.specification.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
prps java.vm.specification.version = 1.0
prps java.vm.vendor = Sun Microsystems Inc.
prps java.vm.version = 20.2-b06
prps line.separator = 
prps log4j.configuration = file:/C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\webapp/WEB-INF/logConfiguration.properties
prps os.arch = x86
prps os.name = Windows Server 2008 R2
prps os.version = 6.1
prps package.definition =     sun.,java.,org.apache.catalina.,org.apache.coyote.,org.apache.tomcat.,org.apache.jasper.
prps path.separator = ;
prps RUN_UNDER_ECLIPSE = false
prps shared.loader = 
prps sun.arch.data.model = 32
prps sun.boot.class.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\sunrsasign.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\lib\modu
prps sun.boot.library.path = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\Java\jre\bin
prps sun.jnu.encoding = Cp1252
prps sun.management.compiler = HotSpot Tiered Compilers
prps sun.net.client.defaultConnectTimeout = 15000
prps sun.net.client.defaultReadTimeout = 20000
prps sun.os.patch.level = Service Pack 1
prps tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled = true
prps tomcat.util.scan.DefaultJarScanner.jarsToSkip = bootstrap.jar,commons-daemon.jar,tomcat-juli.jar,annotations-api.jar,el-api.jar,jsp-api.jar,servlet-api.jar,catalina.jar,catalina-ant.jar,catalina-ha.jar,catalina-tribes.jar,jasper.jar,jasper-el.jar,ecj-*.jar,tomcat-api.jar,tomcat-util.jar,tomcat-coyote.jar,tomcat-dbcp.jar,tomcat-i18n-en.jar,tomcat-i18n-es.jar,tomcat-i18n-fr.jar,tomcat-i18n-ja.jar,commons-beanutils*.jar,commons-codec*.jar,commons-collections*.jar,commons-dbcp*.jar,commons-digester*.jar,
prps user.country = US
prps user.dir = C:\Windows\system32
prps user.home = C:\
prps user.language = en
prps user.name = RAJSERVER$
prps user.timezone = America/Chicago
prps user.variant = 
syskey CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
syskey CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
syskey CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files
syskey COMPUTERNAME = RAJSERVER
syskey ComSpec = C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
syskey FP_NO_HOST_CHECK = NO
syskey JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre
syskey LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local
syskey NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 4
syskey OS = Windows_NT
syskey Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\company\application\resources;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_24\bin;
syskey PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py;.pyw
syskey PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = x86
syskey PROCESSOR_ARCHITEW6432 = AMD64
syskey PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 23 Stepping 10, GenuineIntel
syskey PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6
syskey PROCESSOR_REVISION = 170a
syskey ProgramData = C:\ProgramData
syskey ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files (x86)
syskey ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)
syskey ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files
syskey PSModulePath = C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
syskey PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public
syskey SystemDrive = C:
syskey SystemRoot = C:\Windows
syskey TEMP = C:\Windows\TEMP
syskey TMP = C:\Windows\TEMP
syskey USERDOMAIN = WORKGROUP
syskey USERNAME = RAJSERVER$
syskey USERPROFILE = C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile
syskey windir = C:\Windows
```

Comment: How does environment look like? Let him open cmd, then type `set` and paste output here (unless you see it already).

Answer (score 1):

Check out ***JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS*** environmental variable, it might contain something like

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-agentlib:hprof"
```